# Converting T based timestamp to local datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded a csv file to a dataframe. However, there is no Date column but timestamp and it's format is `2018-06-04T18:00:00-05:00`

I'm trying to find the correct way to convert it to local datetime. I am using following tricky way to convert it but i think there should be a better stable way. And mine doesn't even convert it

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('T', ' ').split('-')[0]
```

output:

```
2018-06-04 18:00:00
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `pd.to_datetime(df.Date)`.  It should convert to local time.

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer. Your solution works great :)

Comment: No point if your problem is already solved. Happy coding!